According to the 4 Madhabs, Are We Supposed To Be More Lax With People With Higher Social Positions?

“No one will be absolved because of a transgression against religious law, except in the case of people of high social position, who will be treated accordingly, as the hadith stipulates: ‘Forgive those in elevated social position,’ since for them corporal punishment is more painful.”
— Abd Al-Majid Ibn Abdun, in The Myth of the Andalusian Paradise, by Dario Fernandez Morera

I apologize for not providing a direct for this narration. I originally came across this passage that was referenced in the book above. They attributed the quote to Ibn Abdun, and not only that, quoted him providing a hadith that propagates his argument.
The focus of this ticket is as follows:

What is the reliability of this attribution to Ibn Abdun?
How well reflected is this position within the mainstream/ classical understanding Islamic jurisprudence; the opinions of the fuquha within the 4 madhabs?
Most importantly, what is the source and authenticity of this supposed hadith Ibn Abdun provided?


Hudood punishments can not be altered nor forgiven once the case has been brought to the authorities and evidence is established. They have been commanded by Allah categorically and it is obligatory to carry out His commands.

لا خلاف في حد الزنا والشرب والسكر والسرقة أنه لا يحتمل العفو والصلح والإبراء بعد ما ثبت بالحجة؛ لأنه حق الله تعالى خالصا، لا حق للعبد فيه فلا يملك إسقاطه
There is no difference regarding the hadd for zina, drinking and theft that they are not eligible for forgiveness, reconciliation or exoneration after proof has been established, for they are purely the rights of Allah and man has no right to waive them
— Badaa’i’ al-Sanaa’i’

They can not be waived regardless of the perpetrator's status:

يا أيها الناس إنما ضل من قبلكم أنهم كانوا إذا سرق الشريف تركوه، وإذا سرق الضعيف فيهم أقاموا عليه الحد، وايم الله لو أن فاطمة بنت محمد سرقت لقطع محمد يدها
O people! The nations before you went astray because if a noble person committed theft, they used to leave him, but if a weak person among them committed theft, they used to inflict the legal punishment on him. By Allah, if Fatima, the daughter of Muhammad committed theft, Muhammad will cut off her hand.
— Bukhari

Qisas can not be altered or forgiven, except by the victim or by his guardians (heirs) if the victim has died. See Quran 2:178, Quran 5:45
Ta'zeer is given at the discretion of the judge on a case by case basis. He may choose to impose a lenient punishment (such as a verbal reprimand) for someone whom he thinks will be sufficiently deterred by it. He can also choose to impose harsh punishments when he feels that it is appropriate in that particular situation. There is disagreement on whether Ta'zeer can be forgiven entirely.
The Hadith you have quoted is likely this one:

أقيلوا ذوي الهيئات عثراتهم إلا الحدود
Forgive the people of good qualities their slips, but not faults to which prescribed penalties apply.
— Abu Dawud, Bulugh al-Maram,  Musnad Ahmad

It is considered weak by some and authentic by others based on corroborating reports. It means that if a virtuous person with good reputation commits a sin then the ta'zeer punishments can be waived from him.
Also see Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah and https://islamqa.info/en/answers/12797/

Who amongst those graded it sahih, and If we were to assume that hadith is authentic, would the matn apply to individuals who transgressed against the rights of others?
